# Using SSH in check of Consul

Tags: ssh, docker, containers, healthcheck, consul

I have a server with a dockerized Consul Agent (CA). In this CA, I want to run a script from the host who checks how many disk space left in a service check.

For this, I created a service in the CA :

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "disk-usage-var-re7", 
    "tags": [
      "type:check",
      "env:re7"
    ],
    "checks": [
      {
        "id": "disk-usage-var-re7",
        "name": "Disk Usage /var RE7",
        "args": [
          "sh",
          "-c",
          "ssh consul@hostserver 'disk_usage.sh /dev/mapper/centos-var'"
        ],
        "interval": "5s",
        "timeout": "30s"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, when Consul runs him, I got this error : `Host key verification failed.`

I am using the official Docker image from Consul (Alpine), version 1.6.1, and I executed these commands in the container :

```
docker exec consul apk add openssh
docker exec -it consul ssh-keygen -t rsa

docker cp consul:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp

su consul
umask 077 && mkdir ~/.ssh
umask 077 && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub > /home/consul/.ssh/authorized_keys
rm -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```

When I try

```
docker exec -it consul ssh consul@hostserver 'disk_usage.sh /dev/mapper/centos-var'
```

The first time, SSH asks me :

```
The authenticity of host 'hostserver (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:MlsT6sDr9xXuOurqBJu4e+a8m2De3Lu4ctJSB+5RNmk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'hostserver' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

And after that, the script still works. But not with the Consul's check.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what happened.
The default user in the container is `root`, but the user who starts Consul is `consul`.

So you have to run the container as the `consul` user specifying `-u consul` and use ssh-keygen with the correct user.

Now take a look at the correct commands :

```
docker exec -it -u consul consul ssh-keygen -t rsa

docker cp consul:/home/consul/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp

su consul
cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub > /home/consul/.ssh/authorized_keys
rm -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```

And the script works !